# kivy referencing from a different class

Tags: python, kivy

Please how do I reference a member of class A in class B

```
Builder.load_string("""
<Main>
do_scroll_x: True
do_scroll_y: False
bar_width: 20
padding: 10
Carousel:
    id: caro_slider
    #direction: 'top'
    padding: 10
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "one two three"
        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            background_color: 1, 0.1 ,0.1, 1
            pos_hint: {'right': 1}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '74sp', '35sp'
            on_press: caro_slider.load_next()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "five six seven"
        Button:
            text: "Click me"
            background_color: 1, 0.1 ,0.1, 1
            on_press: root.show_popup_item()
            size_hint: .6, .2
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'bottom': 1}
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_y: '35sp'
            size_hint: 1, 0
            Button:
                text: 'Previous'
                pos_hint: {'left': 1}
                size_hint: None, None
                size: '74sp', '35sp'
                on_press: caro_slider.load_previous()
            Button:
                text: 'Next'
                background_color: 1, 0.1 ,0.1, 1
                pos_hint: {'right': 1}
                size_hint: None, None
                size: '74sp', '35sp'
                on_press: caro_slider.load_next()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, None
        Label:
            text: "Please choose your choice"
            size_hint: None, None
        Label:
            text: ''
            size_hint: None, None
        GridLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, None
            rows: 1
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: '35sp'
            CheckBox:
                id: chk_box_4
                height: '35sp'
                group: root.group_list
                size_hint: None, None
                on_active: root.chk_chk(self)
            Label:
                text: "Four over there"
                height: '35sp'
                size_hint: None, None
        Button:
            text: 'Previous'
            background_color: 1, 0.1 ,0.1, .5
            pos_hint: {'left': 1}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '74sp', '35sp'
            on_press: caro_slider.load_previous()

# the popup
<Pops>
    title: "Welcome!"
    auto_dismiss: False
    background_color: 0.1, 0.1 , 0.8, 0.9
    size: 400, 250
    size_hint: None, None
    title_height: '40sp'
    separator_height: '1sp'
    separator_color: 1,1,1,1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "Thanks and praises"
            id: sub_title
            max_lines: 5
            size_hint: None, None
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0, 'center_x': 0}
        Label:
            id: composition
            text: "Thanks be to GOD for this to [ref=work]work[/ref] and not to work."
            markup: True
            size_x: self.parent.size[0]
            on_ref_press: print 'clicked the link', self.ids.caro_slider.slides     ------> here is the problem
        Button:
            id: close_button
            text: "Click to close"
            background_color: 1, 0.1 ,0.1, 1
            size_hint: .5, .5
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            on_press: root.dismiss()
""")
```

Comment: You need to post a small and clear piece of code showing the problem, not all your of code. Also, it is not at all clear what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You need some reference to class A from class B. A simple general way to do it is to store the reference in your App class (i.e. `App.get_running_app().classa = a`) then reference it with `App.get_running_app().classa`. In specific cases there might be better places to put it than cluttering up your App though, for instance in the common parent of both class instances.